# How to update the Tomcat in NetBeans IDE 8.2 to version 8.5?

Tags: tomcat8, netbeans-8

I have downloaded Tomcat 8.5 and installed it in "C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.24".

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2, it comes with Tomcat 8.0, how can I update it to run with Tomcat 8.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Service` tab (by default, it's on the left navigation panel, next to `Projects` and `Files`) and right click on `Servers` and select `Add Server...`

Choose to add a new `Apache Tomcat or TomEE`, and then fill up all the fields and click Finish!